# XCode static analyzer: access to instance variable results in a dereference of null pointer

Tags: iphone, ios6, memory-leaks, code-analysis

Running an analysis on my app results memory leaks in the code. I don't really know what that means. Below is a screen of the error:[image]

Comment: You think anybody can see anything in your screenshot?

Comment: analyzer found something in your `lowestCostNodeInArray:` mehtod that `nil` is returned. P.S. your Obj-C code style is awful. Use named parameters ALWAYS.

Comment: Hay @PetroKorienev, sorry for delayed reply :) but neither screenshot is unclear nor my code seems awful and  as I can see I already used NAMED parameters (x & y co-ordinates will remain as x & y). Anyways thanks for suggestion!